# IOS Swift : Half Black screen on UITextview keyboard after dismiss

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uitextview

I am using TableviewController to display Combination of textfields and textview. I designed separate view which is included textview and assigned into Tableview cell.
When I enter the data one by one in textfield and when click the custom cell textview view get scrolled up and after dismiss the keyboard I can see half black screen and even navigation bar also moved up. I can’t reset the window this is will reset only I relaunch the app.

I gave resginfirstresponder, view.endediting, appdelegate.window.endediting also. Still no use

I noticed while I face this half black screen issue and I received a call after call dismiss then the view got reset and looking correctly.

Anybody please help me how resolve the issue.

I have attached the screenshot for reference [image: Halfblackscreen]

Comment: Does all your keyboard handling comes from tableViewController itself? Or you have any extra code?

Comment: Are you moving the view upward manually when the keyboard shows? And do you move the view back down when the keyboard hides?

Comment: @Tj3n  I using IQKeyboardManager. for giving option for Next , Previous button in Keyboard. and Manually added code to focus the textField while clicking on . But removed both code and checked still this issue happening.

Comment: @Adeel No i am not handling that part.

Comment: @kumaresh tell `IQKeyboardManager ` to stop handle keyboard on that screen, because tableViewController already have keyboard handling integrated

Comment: @Tj3n Yes i did i disabled IQkeyboardManager for that class alone. But still problem exist.

Comment: @kumaresh how did you resolved this issue? Kindly guide me. I am also facing same issue, when ever IQKeyboardManager hides view got shrink and quarter below screen got the black.